# save Blob to video file in database Django Rest Api

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

i am receiving a blob file from front end and want to save it into db in video format

here is my views.py

```
class VideoUploadViews(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser )

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            # file = request.data['video']
            # print(file)
            serializer = VideoSerializer(data=request.data)
            print("serializer", serializer)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                res = serializer.save()
                if res:
                    json = serializer.data
                    # print("json", json)
                    json['message'] = 'Video Uploaded Successfully'
                    return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except:
            print('no file')
```

i am able to save the file into native blob format but i want it to be a video file. 
i don't know how to convert a blob to file format(video), please guide...
any help will be appreciated...
thanks in advance